# checkbox.checked = true; but the checkbox not visually ticked

Tags: c#, asp.net

Press a button on the form which opens a modal form and, the on load is doing a filling in.

I have a few checkboxes that have the checked = true if data in the `SqlDataReader` is 1/0.

```
if (myDr.GetBoolean(7)){chkDriverNoShow.Checked = true;}
```

but on the model form, I can see the checkbox but it is not ticked.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDriverNoShow" runat="server" Text="Collection Driver No Show?"/>
```

If the field is checked by the user this is triggered which I would like to happen from the C#.

```java
$("#<%= chkDriverNoShow.ClientID %>").change(function () {
                showHideControls();
```

I have debugged to check the Boolean value and can confirm that the `chkDriverNoShow.checked` is set as true once the modal form has popped up. but still the box is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, how you open the 2nd modal popup form is going to matter a lot here.

Without seeing such code, then we quite guessing here.

So, say a button to click, and a Text box + check box is in the model popup.

In this example, we using jQuery, and jQuery.UI (jQuery.UI dialog).

So, you have to ensure you have both jQuery, and jQuery.UI added to your web page.

So, then this markup:

```
        <h3>enter hotel ID</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View Hotel"
            OnClick="cmdView_Click" CssClass="btn" />


        <div id = "mypopdiv" style="display:none">

            <h3>HotelName</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Text="Hotel Active" />

        </div>

        <script>
            function mypop() {

                myDialog = $("#mypopdiv")

                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Hotel Information",
                    modal: true,
                    sizable: true,
                    width: '380',
                    closeText: "",
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
```

So, we have a button click. That button click will load the hotel record, and then load up the controls in our "popdiv". We then pop the modal dialog and display the results.

So, it stands to reason that before you pop the modal dialog, you need to first load up the controls. We load up the values with sever side code, and then of course inject the script to run which pops up the modal dialog.

The code behind is thus this:

```
    protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtID.Text;
        DataTable rstHotel = General.MyRstP(cmd);

        txtHotel.Text = rstHotel.Rows[0]["HotelName"].ToString();
        chkActive.Checked = (bool)rstHotel.Rows[0]["Active"];

        // now pop the dialog
        string sJava = "mypop()";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "mypopedit", sJava, true);

    }
```

And the result is thus this:

[image]

Of course, one becomes fast tired of typing code over and over to load a data table, and thus I have a general code class for such "helper" routines, and that code was this:

```
    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

So, your checkbox should be showing the correct value, but you need to make sure that you loaded up the control values before you pop up and display the modal dialog.

Comment: Thank you. That was super helpful, laid out and explained well. I had missed in my popup script function something was changing the state.
again thank you for the help and your time.